# Can't get the selected group?

Tags: jquery

```
 <select class="" id="buyCountriesSel"></select>
```

load it with :

```
  $('#buyCountriesSel').append($('<optgroup id="abc" label="USA">'));
    for (var key in statesCodesUS)  $('#buyCountriesSel').append($('<option></option>').val(key).text(statesCodesUS[key]) );
    $('#buyCountriesSel').append($('</optgroup>'));
```

read it with :

```
   $('#buyCountriesSel').on('change', function() {
     var selected = $( "#buyCountriesSel option:selected" );
       var area = selected.closest('optgroup').attr("id"); // .parent() also not work
       alert(area);
   });
```

Expected to get **USA**. This will give me the `buyCountriesSel` object, and not the group with `label="USA"`

Using `parent()` instead of `closest` also not working, trying to check `.label` will also produce `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append()` doesn't concatenate HTML fragments, it creates DOM elements. You need to append the options to the optgroup, not the select.

```js
var usa_group = $('<optgroup id="abc" label="USA">');
for (var key in statesCodesUS) {
  usa_group.append($('<option></option>', {
    value: key,
    text: statesCodesUS[key]
  }));
}
$('#buyCountriesSel').append(usa_group);
```

```html
<select class="" id="buyCountriesSel"></select>
```

Comment: but you never close the optgroup, how is that ?

Comment: There's no opening and closing in the DOM. There's just a node in the DOM tree.